# Minecraft crashes on a ubuntu 11.04 system with an EVGA GT 240 video card

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, ubuntu

I have a computer with Minecraft It runs Ubuntu 11.04 The game freezes sometimes and it outputs this bug report:

```
System: Linux 2.6.38-10-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 15:07:17 UTC 2011 x86_64
X Vendor: The X.Org Foundation
X Vendor Release: 11001000
Selinux: No
Accessibility: Disabled
GTK+ Theme: Ambiance
Icon Theme: ubuntu-mono-dark
GTK+ Modules: gnomesegvhandler, canberra-gtk-module

Memory status: size: 2434789376 vsize: 2434789376 resident: 723947520 share: 45584384 rss: 723947520 rss_rlim: 18446744073709551615
CPU usage: start_time: 1310434859 rtime: 21738 utime: 19093 stime: 2645 cutime:0 cstime: 0 timeout: 0 it_real_value: 0 frequency: 100



----------- .xsession-errors ---------------------
(nautilus:1955): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed
(nautilus:1955): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed
(nautilus:1955): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed
(nautilus:1955): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed
Could not locate Tomboy on D-Bus. Perhaps it's not running?
** (gnome-session:1874): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1874): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1874): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1874): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1874): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1874): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: are you using openJDK or Java?

Comment: Sun Java From Sun installed via repo

Comment: Minecraft has a lot of problems running on the 64-bit JRE.  Is it possible to run 32-bit code in 64-bit Linux?  If not, I'm afraid you're SOL.

Comment: @BlueRaja Doesent work changed java to ia32

Comment: Anybody here???

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct PasteBin?! This looks totally unrelated to your problem. Also, please start Minecraft from the Terminal to see any possible error messages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minecraft crashes on ubuntu system](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21373/minecraft-crashes-on-ubuntu-system)

Comment: I play Minecraft on Gentoo 64-bit (and JRE 64-bit) and nvidia card with proprietary drivers. No issues so far. But, as @Bobby said, the information you posted is kinda useless, jtl999, because it does not contain anything related to Minecraft nor the crash. We can't help you further without more information.

Answer (score 2):

Update your drivers to the latest version, and also Minecraft. I'm sorry I don't know more about running Minecraft on Ubuntu...

Comment: Running latest Nvidia Driver

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Ubuntu, but [several](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1791767.html) [similar](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/738203) [reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eog/+bug/754622) suggest that this is a problem with Nautilus in 11.04 and nothing to do with Minecraft.  Unfortunately, not much is offered in the way of advice, beyond `sudo killall nautilus` after the crash to get things working again.

General troubleshooting may still help, however:

1. Ensure your drivers (especially video) are up to date.
2. [Upgrade the copy of LWJGL](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Update_LWJGL) embedded in Minecraft.
3. Minecraft has been known to *sometimes* run better in Wine than natively.  If you have Wine installed, it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I use the java command to increase the max memory allowed for the game and it makes in way less buggy on 64bit Ubuntu. like

```
 java -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft.jar
```

that will run it at 1GB of ram to 2 GB of ram allocated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that when running Minecraft on Ubuntu it is buggy. I would advise downloading Wine so you can run it in "Windows."

Comment: Java is java.. Why would you run something native to Linux in wine?

Comment: @Simon Sheehan — Because the native libraries used by Minecraft (particularly LWJGL) don't work quite as well on Linux as on Windows.  I've heard of a number of problems solved by getting Wine into the picture.

Comment: Did you actually have these issues?

Comment: @Simon Sheehan — Personally?  No, it was a friend who runs Gentoo. He had serious control issues and ended up using Wine to work around them.  While researching it, we found others having control, video, and sound issues who'd gone to Wine as well.